# Logstash delay of log sending

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm forwarding application logs to elasticsearch, while performing some grok filters before.

The application has a timestamp field and there's the timestamp field of logstash itself.
We regularly check the difference between those timestamp, and on many cases the delay is very big, meaning the log took very long time to be shipped to elasticsearch.

I'm wondering how can I isolate the issue to know if the delay is coming from logstash or elasticsearch.

Example logstash scrape config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/app/app-core/_logs/app-core.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "(^[a-zA-Z.]+(?:Error|Exception).+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\t+)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {
  if "multiline" not in [tags]{
    json {
      source => "message"
      remove_field => ["[request][body]","[response][body][response][items]"]
    }
  }
  else {
    grok {
      pattern_definitions => { APPJSON => "{.*}"  }
      match => { "message" => "%{APPJSON:appjson} %{GREEDYDATA:stack_trace}"}
      remove_field => ["message"]
    }
    json {
      source => "appjson"
      remove_field => ["appjson"]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch-logs.internal.app.io:9200"]
    index => "logstash-core-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "logs"
  }
}
```

We tried adjusting the number of workers and batch size, no value we tried reduced the delay:

```
pipeline.workers: 9
pipeline.output.workers: 9
pipeline.batch.size: 600
pipeline.batch.delay: 5
```

Nothing was done on the elasticsearch side because I think the issue is with logstash, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you check the time diff between host which provide the timestamp of the event and  logstash/elastic/kibana, sometimes this could be a cause of this kind of issue.

Comment: `date` produces the same output on every machine.

Comment: ok, to have more visibility on which state could take time, you could add a technical timestamp on logstash side to have more details on each step.

Comment: What does very big delay mean in terms of hours/minutes/seconds?

Comment: @YLR sounds good. how do i add the timestamp? and does it indicate the time before filtering? or before the output stage?

Comment: @Filip 100 minutes is the best case we have. Sometimes it's 4-5 hours delay

Comment: And you could check monitoring api to have other details : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-logstash.html

Comment: I suspect multiline mechanism that could quick cause leaks in some case

Comment: you could add current date in filter with this kind of code :      ruby {
        code => "event.set('logstash_processed_at', Time.now());"
        }

Comment: A multiline codec will not flush an event into the pipeline until it sees the beginning of the next event unless the [auto_flush_interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#plugins-codecs-multiline-auto_flush_interval) option is set. If there is a one hour interval between messages in the log file then every event will be an hour "late".